# Is my site safe from XSS if I replace all '<' with '&lt;'?

Tags: security, xss

I'm wondering what the bare minimum to make a site safe from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is.

If I simply replace `<` with `&lt;` in all user submitted content, will my site be safe from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends hugely on context.

Also, encoding less than only isn't that flash of an idea. You should just encode all characters which have special meaning and could be used for XSS...

- `<`
- `>`
- `"`
- `'`
- `&`

For a trivial example of where encoding the less than won't matter is something like this...

> Welcome to Dodgy Site. Please link to your homepage.

Malicious user enters...

```
http://www.example.com" onclick="window.location = 'http://nasty.com'; return false;
```

Which obviously becomes...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="window.location = 'http://nasty.com'; return false;">View user's website</a>
```

Had you encoded double quotes, that attack would not be valid.

Comment: @alex - Do you think only encoding `less than` would be okay if the only place I ever outputted the content was `<p>$outputcontenthere</p>`?

Comment: @Kyle Perhaps, but I wouldn't take the chance. Write a proper encoder for HTML output. It isn't worth taking the risk.

Comment: In your example, you should also escape input which starts with `javascript:`

Comment: @Baju Sure. But I was trying to limit my example to one that proves that encoding angle brackets only is still exploitable.

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to escape all user input, regardless of what it contains.

Comment: I copy pasted your HTML Hex into a test page, similar to how I would output something serverside. The text `<script>alert('xss!');</script>` appears on the page, but it doesn't actually run the script. How would the HTML Hex or the Base 64 Encoding end up getting run?

Answer (score 2):

There are also case where the encoding of the page counts. Ie - if your page character set is not correct or does not match in all applicable spots, then there are potential vulnerabilities. See http://openmya.hacker.jp/hasegawa/security/utf7cs.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the framework you are using, many now have an input validation module. A key piece I tell software students when I do lectures is **USE THE INPUT VALIDATION MODULES WHICH ALREADY EXIST!**

reinventing the wheel is often less effective than using the tried and tested modules which exist already. .Net has most of what you might need built in - really easy to whitelist (where you know the only input allowed) or blacklist (a bit less effective as known 'bad' things always change, but still valuable)

Answer (score 0):

If you escape all user input you should be safe.

That mean EVERYTHING EVERYWHERE it shows up.  Even a username on a profile.

Comment: ESPECIALLY the username.  Funny things can happen when a user on a social website is able to put JavaScript into his username.  A list of users is shown quite frequently on those kind of sites... :-)  That being said, you really should escape EVERY user input, or rather every untrusted input.

Comment: @paprika: Everyone would be affected by a username... I didn't think about that.

Comment: Did you really name your son `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--`?